# Acumatica Installation Error-Adding Instance

Tags: acumatica

Network path was not found.
Probably you do not have IIS?

I'm getting this error, from fresh install of OS and other tools for development. I DO Have IIS installed, version 10 and tweaked registry for Acumatica to see the Registry of IIS on my local computer.

any fix? Thanks! wasted my day looking for a fix on this.

Comment: Please add some screenshots, logs and more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, this made me feel depressed, lol. 
and also reformatting my local pc.

and the answer, I just enabled "Remote Registry" in the services.

I'm running Windows 10 Version 1803, but on 1803 below it is fine.

Hope it can help others going on to this matter on newer versions of Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Yes, obviously logs appear in log file. But to answer how to resolve the issue - I had a problem on win 10 and IIS was installed. You were missing some components from listed component folders. As per install guide 
 https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(56))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=8ed6a834-e49d-4e9a-9f44-2ce4df048983

It has resolved issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this for reference since you already found a solution.

When Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard encounters an error it appends the error in a 'log.txt' file in Acumatica ERP directory. You might find additional details to resolve the error in there:

```
    ===================2018-09-21 11:39:38 AM===================
    Configuration Wizard (Version '18.200.0075') started at 2018-09-21 11:39:38 AM

    ===================2018-09-24 10:22:13 AM===================
    Configuration Wizard (Version '18.200.0075') started at 2018-09-24 10:22:13 AM

    ===================2018-09-24 10:24:08 AM===================
    Сan't get access to the IIS server. Try to use administrator rights.

    ===================2018-09-24 10:24:13 AM===================
    Сan't get access to the IIS server. Try to use administrator rights.

    ===================2018-09-24 10:33:56 AM===================
    Configuration Wizard (Version '18.200.0075') started at 2018-09-24 10:33:56 AM

    ===================2018-09-24 10:36:22 AM===================
    Not all required components are installed on the internet information services.
    Please check that Application Development and Common HTTP Features are installed correctly.
```

Answer (score 0):

What system locale do you have?
There is an [issue](http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug) when installing Acumatica on Turkish locale.

It should be fixed in the latest beta. To workaround on previous Acumatica versions try switching to English locale.
Perhaps some other locales can be affected as well.